# Dynamic path in jsonb_set function

Tags: java, json, json.net, sql-update

```
UPDATE users
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{user,name}', '"sunil"', FALSE)
WHERE id = 1;
```

In the above query for example, how can i pass the path (here "user,name") dynamically through a variable like can i store the path in a string variable and pass here that variable. Unable to do it so please provide a working solution.

I need that somehow i can pass that path through a variable so that i can use it dynamically for different objects with different paths.

Comment: You tagged this [tag:java] and [tag:json.net] (which is not a Java library, it is a c#/.NET library), but are you actually using [tag:postgresql]?  How is Java related to your question?  By [tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) your question with the language & framework(s) you are actually using you will attract the attention of people familiar with them and who can answer your question.  See [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know that how can i pass the path (of the nested json i want to update) dynamically using a variable i.e. i can store in a string s and then pass that s in the place of path.